# make expandviewlist selectable

Tags: expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'm very new to programming, and just learning as much as I can.  I'm trying to create a pretty simple app for our company to print labels.  I've created an expandablelistadapter and managed to get all of our materials in the view.  I'm however not able to select any of the child items and have it show up in the app. Here is the code I've use for the adapter.  I've tried a few options mentioned on this site and none have worked for me.  I'm sure it's something simple that I'm leaving out.

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

```
private Context context;
private List<String> expandableListTitle;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail) {
    this.context = context;
    this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
    this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
            .get(expandedListPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return expandedListPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
    expandedListTextView.setText(expandedListText);
    return convertView;

}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
    return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
    return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.expandableListTitle.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
    return listPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }
    TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
    listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return false;
```